# USB Debugging Re-Authorization Required After "Always Allow"

Tags: android, debugging, usb, appium, adb

I use an Android phone to do some basic Bluetooth compatibility testing in a remote testing environment.

In order to automate the test phone with Appium or view it's interface using Vysor, I have to allow a "USB Debugging" pop-up. This pop up gives the option to "Always Allow Connections from this PC" which I select each time. However, this authorization seems to reset after some period of time and I can't figure out why.

Multiple users access the phone from their own user accounts, and USB Debugging has to be authorized for each of these users individually, but whenever the authorization resets, it resets for all users and all users must be individually re-authorized.

These resets tend to happen on average about once per month.

My first thought was the phone must be updating, but Automatic Security Updates are disabled on the test phone, so I don't think that is the issue.

The last time I had to re-authorize USB Debugging, I noticed this pop-up on windows which occurred suspiciously the day before I had to re-authorize, but I don't know what caused this.

[image: Potentially related pop-up in Windows]

Does anyone know what might be causing these resets? Given how our testing is remote, it can be a major inconvenience to re-authorize the phone since the resets occur unpredictably.

Comment: Since Android 12 the adb authorization has an expiration date which can be disabled in developer options on the Android device (not sure how it is named in English).

Comment: Thanks, @Robert. My phone was still running Android 10. I will update software and see if that solves the issue.